# Configure sonar and maven to analyze Webapp

Tags: maven, sonarqube

We need to analyze a webapp using Sonar

The webapp has been developed using java, ejb's and adf.
The structure is as below - Root directory with main workspace .jws
Subdirectories with individual project .jpr's, each having its own pom.xml

```
A
|
| a.jws
| pom.xml
|
| - B
| - B/b.jpr
| - B/pom.xml
| - B/src 
|
| - C
| - C/c.jpr
| - C/pom.xml
| - C/src
|
```

We build the Ear for the webapp with maven from the root directory containing the main .jws and main pom.xml

A/sonar-project.properties has entries as below

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=A
sonar.projectName=A
sonar.projectVersion=v1


# Set modules IDs
sonar.modules=B,C

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java

B.sonar.projectBaseDir=B
B.sonar.projectName=B

C.sonar.projectBaseDir=C
C.sonar.projectName=C
```

When i execute mvn sonar:sonar from /A, the build output shows A sucess, and skipped B, C

Sonar dashboard shows up A with 0 LOC covered and no issues reported

Our objective is to get mvn sonar:sonar to build A, B, C and report data in Sonar dashboard

Any pointers ?

Comment: You're talking about "mvn sonar:sonar" but also about "sonar-project.properties" file: are you using Maven or the Sonar Runner to execute an analysis? You can't use both at the same time.

Comment: I have tested mvn sonar:sonar first without sonar-project.properties, then with it, in both cases mvn shows success for A, and skipped for B, C

Comment: As Fabrice said, sonar-project.properties is not used by Maven SonarQube analysis (mvn sonar:sonar) so you can forget it if you want to use Maven to analyse your project. What is the Maven packaging of modules B & C ?